# ArcGIS ImportError: The login failed because the arcpy library could not be found in your Python environment

Tags: python, arcgis

I'm trying to follow this [tutorial](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/samples/count-cars-in-aerial-imagery-using-deep-learning/). My code is:

```py
from arcgis.gis import GIS
gis = GIS("home")
```

When executing I get the following error:

```
ImportError: The login failed because the arcpy library could not be found in your Python environment. Try logging in with a different set of credentials.
```

Do I need to download something else? Should I replace "home" with a url / API key?

I've created a free trial account with Esri and tried following these steps to try to download ArcGIS Pro, but the information seems outdated as I don't have the "Request Permissions" button to click on mentioned here in step 2:

https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/get-started/download-arcgis-pro.htm